# Changing the base learner in MOA Framework

Tags: ensemble-learning, moa

I have two questions related to ensemble learning for data streams.

1. If you have used MOA framework, could you please tell me how to change the base learner for a given algorithm. For instance, I want to change it for OnlineAdaBoost, OnlineAdaC2, onlineSMOTEBagging, and OnlineRUSBoost. The base learner for all of these is Adaptive Random Forest and I want it to be Hoeffding Tree. When I click EDIT to change the baseLearner, nothing happens.
2. The algorithms in Q1 use ARF as baselearner by default, whereas ARF uses Hoeffding Tree as base learner. Can we say that these algorithms indirectly use Hoeffding Tree as base learner? For a comparison, I must use Hoeffding Tree as base learner for these.

https://javadoc.io/static/nz.ac.waikato.cms.moa/moa/2020.12.0/moa/classifiers/meta/imbalanced/OnlineRUSBoost.html
https://javadoc.io/static/nz.ac.waikato.cms.moa/moa/2020.12.0/moa/classifiers/meta/imbalanced/OnlineSMOTEBagging.html
https://javadoc.io/static/nz.ac.waikato.cms.moa/moa/2020.12.0/moa/classifiers/meta/imbalanced/OnlineAdaC2.html
https://javadoc.io/static/nz.ac.waikato.cms.moa/moa/2020.12.0/moa/classifiers/meta/imbalanced/OnlineAdaBoost.html

If more information is required, I can provide it.

Tx.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MOA GUI, you can right click in configure textbox to change the command. It was hard to find this, but the base learner could be changed manually using this option.